# Socket.io with express backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I want to implement *socket.io* on my *express* backend to inform the user about the task's state during the request (state is like started, processing, ...)

So, user clicks a button, socket connection opens and waits for events, during long running request backend emits data to client and finally response comes and request finishes, the result is shown to user.

in my **index.js** file, which I bootstrap the application

```
const express = require('express'),
app = express(),
router = require('./router'),
server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
/* other required modules*/

server.listen(config.port,'127.0.0.1');
router(app, io);
```

in my **router.js**

```
const taskController = require('./controllers/task');
/* other required modules*/

module.exports = function(app, io) {
  const apiRoutes = express.Router();
  apiRoutes.post('/task/do', taskController.doTask(io));
}
```

in my **task.js**

```
exports.doAnalysis = function(socket){
 return function(req, res){
   socket.emit('task-start', 'Your task is started');
   ...
 }
}
```

When I do this, it emits all the connected clients.

What I want to do is, emit from my controller's functions to only specific client which calls the endpoint so, sender only.

Also, I can't do in my task controller the following snippet:

```
exports.doTask = function(socket){
 return function(req, res){
   socket.on('connection', function(s){
     s.emit('task-start', 'Your task is started');
     ...
   })
 }
}
```

Apparently, passing io object won't work for this scenario.

I know that I should get all socket ids and emit with specific socket id but, 
what is the proper way to do this ?

Comment: I began writing and then realized this question was five years old.  Too bad man - I think it was a great idea and I'd love to see the resolution.  My comment before I realized this was an abandoned question was 'the controller location sounds logical" because how else would you know the information that you need to send the message?  I assume that's your point - location in router, separate module, etc.. ?